# How will Parallel.Foreach behave when Iterating over the results of a method call?

Tags: c#, multithreading, amazon-web-services, parallel-processing

**Scope:**

I am currently implementing an application that uses [Amazon SQS Service](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) as a provider of data for this program to process.

Since I need a parallel processing over the messages dequeued from this queue, this is what I've did.

```
Parallel.ForEach (GetMessages (msgAttributes), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threadCount }, message =>
        {
             // Processing Logic
        });
```

Here's the header of the "GetMessages" method:

```
    private static IEnumerable<Message> GetMessages (List<String> messageAttributes = null)
    {
        // Dequeueing Logic... 10 At a Time

        // Yielding the messages to the Parallel Loop
        foreach (Message awsMessage in messages)
        {
           yield return awsMessage;
        }
    }
```

**How will this work ?:**

My initial thought about how this would work was that the `GetMessages`method would be executed whenever the thread's had no work (or a good number of threads had no work, something like an internal heuristic to measure this). That being said, to me, the `GetMessages` method would than, distribute the messages to the `Parallel.For` working threads, which would process the messages and wait for the `Parallel.For handler` to give them more messages to work.

**Problem? I was wrong...**

The thing is that, I was wrong. Still, I have no idea on what's happening in this situation.

The number of messages being dequeued is way too high, and it grews by powers of 2 every time they get dequeued. The dequeueing count (messsages) goes as following:

1. Dequeue is Called: Returns 80 Messages
2. Dequeue is Called: Returns 160 Messages
3. Dequeue is Called: Returns 320 Messages (and so forth)

After a certain point, the number of messages being dequeued, or, in this case, waiting to be processed by my application is too high and I end up running out of memory.

**More Information:**

I am using thread-safe `InterLocked` operations to increment counters mentioned above.

The number of threads being used is 25 (for the `Parallel.Foreach`)

Each "GetMessages" will return up to 10 messages (as an IEnumerable, yielded).

**Question: What exactly is happening on this scenario ?**

I am having a hard-time trying to figure out what exactly is going on. Is my `GetMessages` method being invoked by each thread once it finishes the "Processing Loop", hence, leading to more and more messages being dequeued ?

Is the call to the "GetMessages", made by a single thread, or is it being called by multiple threads ?

Comment: why are you dequeueing 10 messages at a time. Only a single thread is going to process a single message at a time, so you end up dequeueing 9 too many. This dequeueing is going to happen for each loop.

Comment: As far as I understand, by dequeueing 10 messages, they would be served to 10 different threads on the Parallel.ForEach loop, meaning that the Dequeue would be single-threaded, but the messaging processing itself, would be parallel

Comment: Side note: To my knowledge Parallel.ForEach throttls on speed of execution of tasks, not on query part... Check out "consumer-producer" section of [Patterns for Parallel programming](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222) for some suggestions.

Comment: I think for each iteration you enter in the GetMessage and as such you end up with 9 messages too many. Some tracing in your code will show whether I am right about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's an issue with `Parallel.ForEach` partitioning... Your question is a typical producer / consumer scenario. For such a case, you should have independent logics for dequeuing on one side, and processing on the other. It will respect separation of concerns, and will simplify debugging.

[`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will let you to separate boths : on one side, you add items to be processed, and on the other, you consume them. Here's an example of how to implement it :

You will need the [ParallelExtensionsExtras](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ParallelExtensionsExtras/) nuget package for `BlockingCollection<T>` workload partitioning (`.GetConsumingEnumerable()` in the process method).

```
public static class ProducerConsumer
{
    public static ConcurrentQueue<String> SqsQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<String>();         
    public static BlockingCollection<String> Collection = new BlockingCollection<String>();
    public static ConcurrentBag<String> Result = new ConcurrentBag<String>();

    public static async Task TestMethod()
    {
        // Here we separate all the Tasks in distinct threads
        Task sqs = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Amazon on thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
            while (true)
            {
                ProducerConsumer.BackgroundFakedAmazon(); // We produce 50 Strings each second
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        });
        Task deq = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dequeue on thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
            while (true)
            {
                ProducerConsumer.DequeueData(); // Dequeue 20 Strings each 100ms 
                await Task.Delay(100);
            }
        });

        Task process = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Process on thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
            ProducerConsumer.BackgroundParallelConsumer(); // Process all the Strings in the BlockingCollection
        });

        await Task.WhenAll(c, sqs, deq, process);
    }

    public static void DequeueData()
    {
        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 20))
        {
            String dequeued = null;
            if (SqsQueue.TryDequeue(out dequeued))
            {
                Collection.Add(dequeued);
                Console.WriteLine("Dequeued : " + dequeued);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void BackgroundFakedAmazon()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" ---------- Generate 50 items on amazon side  ---------- ");
        foreach (var data in Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select(i => Path.GetRandomFileName().Split('.').FirstOrDefault()))
            SqsQueue.Enqueue(data + " / ASQS");
    }

    public static void BackgroundParallelConsumer()
    {
        // Here we stay in Parallel.ForEach, waiting for data. Once processed, we are still waiting the next chunks
        Parallel.ForEach(Collection.GetConsumingEnumerable(), (i) =>
        {
            // Processing Logic
            String processedData = "Processed : " + i;
            Result.Add(processedData);
            Console.WriteLine(processedData);
        });

    }
}
```

You can try it from a console app like this :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ProducerConsumer.TestMethod().Wait();
}
```

Comment: That solved my problem, I ended up using a Blocking collection aswell, but with only two threads (Producer and Consumer). Just for curiosity sake, what exactly was happening on my implementation, that led to that weird behavior of the Parallel.For ?

Comment: I suspect the problem was more in the dequeuing logic inside the Parallel.For IEnumerable than in the way you use Parallel.For. Separating concerns often makes it more easy to code things more cleanly, avoiding sides effects like the one you have had.