# Limiting number of threads when dequeuing from a BlockingCollection

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, concurrency, producer-consumer, parallel.foreach

I am currently using this to limit the number of processing threads:

```
Dim ListOfFiles New List(of String) From {...}
Dim parallelOptions As ParallelOptions = New ParallelOptions With {.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 6}
Parallel.ForEach(ListOfFiles, parallelOptions, Sub(F)
                                                    'Process one file
                                               End Sub)
```

which works well because I can control the number of concurrent threads to suit other processing going on simultaneously.

But I need to keep adding items to the list. Instead of a fixed size list, I want to use a `ConcurrentQueue` so that I can continue enqueuing a list of files (from a Producer thread) while the parallel Consumer processing is going on. Clearly `Parallel.ForEach` wont work. I could use a `BlockingCollection` but I cant determine how best to only dequeue items as threads become available and block when they are all busy. Sitting in a loop and counting threads seems ugly.

Any thoughts would be welcome.

Comment: Are you looking for `BlockingCollection` based solution or are you open for [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) or [Channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/)?

Comment: ParallelExtensionsExtra nuget package, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28639744/17034)

Comment: Why won't `Parallel.ForEach` work? `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` will prevent too many threads dequeueing, and the Producer thread you are controlling separately. Keep the two things separate: the Producer thread that enqueues, and the other threads that dequeue

Comment: @Charlieface: The list that I am currently passing as the first parameter has a fixed size. Do you mean I should be passing the BlockingCollection instead? Isn't that a problem if the ConcurrentQueue size keeps changing? How does ForEach work if its not a constant size? Do I dequeue inside Sub(F)? I'm not clear how that would all work.

Comment: @PeterCsala:  I don't know anything about these, thanks for the links, I will have to do some reading. But I guess using BlockingCollection would be preferable.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks Hans I will look at that too.

Comment: It seems like what you're proposing is to watch the collection for new items and spin up threads to process them (up to a limit).  A more natural fit for the interface of `BlockingCollection` might be to have a fixed number of consumer threads that are all waiting on new items and springing into action when `TryTake` returns something.  I would expect them to have minimal cost while they're waiting as I would expect `TryTake` to use the appropriate Windows threading primitives to let them sleep until there's something to take.

Comment: @Craig: Yes that sounds like what I want. My difficulty lies in using a BlockingCollection in a loop when its size is constantly changing. Does TryTake block though? I thought the idea was that it returns immediately regardless of whether it dequeued or not, and that Take blocks?

Comment: Good point, forgot this was a queue. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/implementing-parallel-while-with-parallel-foreach/, I think spin up however many threads you need, and some kind of `while` loop on each consumer thread.

Comment: Re `Take` vs `TryTake`, it depends on the signature.  I think `TryTake` with `Infinite` wait time is functionally equivalent to `Take`.  You're correct that the one-param version of `TryTake` does not block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who commented.

I ended up using `GetComsumingPartitioner` based on the blog article by Stephen Toub here:  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-4-blockingcollectionextensions/

This worked out great.